# NSTextField or NSSecureTextField in NSMenu() as NSMenuItem()

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextfield, nsmenu

I'm currently working on a menubar app and I'm trying to implement a NSTextField or NSSecureTextField.
This is what I do to add NSMenuItems

```
let menu = NSMenu()
menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Save Test Data", action: #selector(AppDelegate.saveData), keyEquivalent: ""))
```

but trying to add a NSTextField like this:

```
menu.addItem(NSTextField)
```

brings this Error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(NSTextField).Type'(aka 'NSTextField.Type') to expected argument type 'NSMenuItem'
```

But how should I implement a NSTextField using NSMenuItem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add other elements as `NSMenuItem` to a menu directly.

To implement a text field you have wrap it in a custom `NSView` and assign the view to the `view` property of the menu item.